# What is the difference between exit and break in a login shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I would like to understand why `exit` behaves differently than `break` in the following command:

```
$ set -o pipefail; true | bash -e -lxc 'while true; do <BREAK/EXIT>; done'; echo $?
```

Is this a bug? Because depending on which one is used, the `~./bash_logout` is called throwing an exit code 1 (because `clear_console -q` fails).

- With `break` -> `exit code 0`

```
$ set -o pipefail; true | bash -e -lxc 'while true; do break; done'; echo $?
+ '[' '' ']'
+ '[' -d /etc/profile.d ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh
+++ /usr/bin/locale-check C.UTF-8
++ eval
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
++ snap_bin_path=/snap/bin
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop ']'
++ snap_xdg_path=/var/lib/snapd/desktop
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
++ '[' 'x5.1.16(1)-release' '!=' x -a x '!=' x -a x = x ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh
++ '[' nl = pt -a en '!=' pt ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/debuginfod.sh ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh
++ '[' tty = wayland ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop ']'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ export XDG_DATA_DIRS
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh
++ '[' tty '!=' wayland ']'
++ return
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh
++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' -o -n '' ']'
++ [[ ehxBc == *i* ]]
++ return 0
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh
++ DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
++ DEFAULT_XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ unset i
+ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
+ '[' -f /home/user/.bashrc ']'
+ . /home/user/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return
+ '[' -d /home/user/bin ']'
+ '[' -d /home/user/.local/bin ']'
+ true
+ break
0
```

- With `exit` -> `exit code 1`

```
$ set -o pipefail; true | bash -e -lxc 'while true; do exit; done'; echo $?
+ '[' '' ']'
+ '[' -d /etc/profile.d ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh
+++ /usr/bin/locale-check C.UTF-8
++ eval
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
++ snap_bin_path=/snap/bin
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop ']'
++ snap_xdg_path=/var/lib/snapd/desktop
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
++ '[' 'x5.1.16(1)-release' '!=' x -a x '!=' x -a x = x ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh
++ '[' nl = pt -a en '!=' pt ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/debuginfod.sh ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh
++ '[' tty = wayland ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop ']'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ export XDG_DATA_DIRS
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh
++ '[' tty '!=' wayland ']'
++ return
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh
++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' -o -n '' ']'
++ [[ ehxBc == *i* ]]
++ return 0
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh
++ DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
++ DEFAULT_XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ unset i
+ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
+ '[' -f /home/user/.bashrc ']'
+ . /home/user/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return
+ '[' -d /home/user/bin ']'
+ '[' -d /home/user/.local/bin ']'
+ true
+ exit
++ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
++ '[' -x /usr/bin/clear_console ']'
++ /usr/bin/clear_console -q
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between exit and break in a login shell

In this case, the difference is in the execution of `.bash_logout` script. It is not executed when non-interactive login shell exits... on it's own. It is executed when non-interactive login shell calls `exit` explicitly.

> When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login shell executes the exit builtin command, Bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

Comment: ah, then it makes sense. But it's a bit funny because the man page just says:
When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.